# I can't install Web Player and AutomationServices on Node Manager(Spotfire Server 7.11.2)

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I installed node manager. But when I try to install Web Player and Automation Services it gives me an error.

I turned off all firewall blocks and windows defender.

Node manager service runs in Administrator user account.

This↓↓ is my log file in nm.

https://community.tibco.com/sites/default/files/answers/2019_06/nm.txt

I would be really grateful if you can give me a solution.

Thanks!

Natasha

[image: Spotfire Node Manager]

[image: Spotfire Node Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the following in order:

1. make sure you have disk space available on the NM machine. restart NM.
2. make sure you have disk space available on the machine hosting the Spotfire database. restart NM and TSS.
3. stop the NM service, delete `/tibco/tsnm/[version]/nm/trust/keystore.p12`, start NM
4. contact TIBCO Support.